# Using InfCloud with Baikal and Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I have my server with Baikal and nginx running and now I want to add the Frontend InfCloud (maybe know as CalDavZap or CalDavMATE).

Baikal is running at `https://mydomain:202/`

I have the `calcard.php` to access calendar and contacts. The file is accessibly under `https://mydomain:202/calcard.php/`

Now I want InfCloud to run under `https://mydomain/cal`.

User and password is `test`
I can already access the login page, but when logging in, following error occurs:

> jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4 Refused to connect to 'https://test:test@mydomain:202/calcard.php/principals/' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'". Note that 'connect-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

and

> [netCheckAndCreateConfiguration: 'PROPFIND https://mydomain:202/calcard.php/principals/'] code: '0' status: 'error' - see https://www.inf-it.com/infcloud/readme.txt (cross-domain setup)

These are my configurations:

InfCloud `config.js`

```
 var globalNetworkCheckSettings={
    href: 'https://mydomain:202/calcard.php/principals/',
    timeOut: 90000,
    lockTimeOut: 10000,
    //checkContentType: true,
    settingsAccount: true,
    delegation: true,
    additionalResources: [],
    hrefLabel: null,
    forceReadOnly: null,
    ignoreAlarms: false,
    backgroundCalendars: []
 }
 var globalUseJqueryAuth=true;
```

And nginx

```
location /cal {
    root /path/to/infcloud;
    dav_methods PUT DELETE MKCOL COPY MOVE;
    dav_ext_methods PROPFIND OPTIONS;
    index index.html;
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/infcloud.access.log;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/infcloud.error.log;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You are now running Baikal on https://mydomain:202 and infoCloud on https://mydomain:443. That is, you are running a cross-domain setup and are hitting the protection mechanisms associated with such a setup.

There are a number of ways to overcome the problem and they are fairly well explained in the readme.txt referenced in the infoCloud error message shown in your original post.

Comment: I added the lines found here http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html to the config of baikal and added the ones mentioned in the readme.txt . But I still get the same error.